# tkinter scrollbar not working for complete table

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, tkinter-canvas, tkintertable

I am trying to display some data in table. I have tried adding a scrollbar to the table to view all the columns of table. But the scrollbar is not getting scrolled to the end of table. It just stops after scrolling a little.

Here is the code I have tried for it:

```
from tkinter import Tk, Toplevel, messagebox, ttk
from tkinter import *


def main():
    main_window = Tk()
    app = info(main_window)
    main_window.mainloop()


class info:
    def __init__(self, root):
        self.root = root
        self.root.title('First window')

        # setting window to the center

        self.root.geometry('1350x700+0+0')  #############
        self.root.resizable(width=False, height=False)  #################

        self.root.configure(background='white')

        table = ttk.Treeview(self.root)  ###########################
        table1 = LabelFrame(self.root, text="Retrieved Data")  ################
        table1.pack(fill="both", expand="yes", padx=20, pady=10)  ###################
        table = ttk.Treeview(table1, height="8")  #################

        table['columns'] = ['Variant_ID', 'Clinical_Type', 'Allelic_ID', 'Clinical_Significance', 'Clinical_Condition',
                            'Allelic_Origin', 'Review_Status', 'Clinical_identifier', 'Cytogenic_Location', 'Variance',
                            'Type']
        table.column('#0', width=120, minwidth=185)
        table.column('Variant_ID', anchor=W, width=120, minwidth=185)
        table.column('Clinical_Type', anchor=CENTER, width=120, minwidth=185)
        table.column('Allelic_ID', anchor=CENTER, width=120, minwidth=185)
        table.column('Clinical_Significance', anchor=CENTER, width=120, minwidth=185)
        table.column('Clinical_Condition', anchor=CENTER, width=120, minwidth=185)
        table.column('Allelic_Origin', anchor=CENTER, width=120, minwidth=185)
        table.column('Review_Status', anchor=CENTER, width=120, minwidth=185)
        table.column('Clinical_identifier', anchor=CENTER, width=120, minwidth=185)
        table.column('Clinical_Type', anchor=CENTER, width=120, minwidth=185)
        table.column('Variance', anchor=CENTER, width=120, minwidth=185)
        table.column('Type', anchor=CENTER, width=120, minwidth=185)

        table.heading('#0', text='Serial No.', anchor=W)
        table.heading('Variant_ID', text='Variant_ID', anchor=W)
        table.heading('Clinical_Type', text='Clinical_Type', anchor=CENTER)
        table.heading('Allelic_ID', text='Allelic_ID', anchor=CENTER)
        table.heading('Clinical_Significance', text='Clinical_Significance', anchor=CENTER)
        table.heading('Clinical_Condition', text='Clinical_Condition', anchor=CENTER)
        table.heading('Allelic_Origin', text='Allelic_Origin', anchor=CENTER)
        table.heading('Review_Status', text='Review_Status', anchor=CENTER)
        table.heading('Clinical_identifier', text='Clinical_identifier', anchor=CENTER)
        table.heading('Cytogenic_Location', text='Cytogenic_Location', anchor=CENTER)
        table.heading('Variance', text='Variance', anchor=CENTER)
        table.heading('Type', text='Type', anchor=CENTER)

        table.pack(side=LEFT)  ##################
        table.place(x=250, y=400)  ##########################
        # VERTICAL SCROLLBAR
        yscrollbar = ttk.Scrollbar(table1, orient=VERTICAL, command=table.yview)  #############
        yscrollbar.pack(side=RIGHT, fill='y')  ##################

        # HORIZONTAL SCROLLBAR
        xscrollbar = ttk.Scrollbar(table1, orient=HORIZONTAL, command=table.xview)  ###################
        xscrollbar.pack(side=BOTTOM, fill='x')  #######################

        table.configure(yscrollcommand=yscrollbar, xscrollcommand=xscrollbar)  ##############


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I will be thankful if someone helps me solve this problem.

Comment: Don't think it is related to your problem but why do you have 2 definitions of `table`?

Comment: `table.configure(yscrollcommand=yscrollbar, xscrollcommand=xscrollbar)` should be `table.configure(yscrollcommand=yscrollbar.set, xscrollcommand=xscrollbar.set)` instead.

Comment: Why do you call `table.pack` and then `table.place`? You shouldn't do that

Comment: It is easier to use `grid()` on the treeview and the scrollbars.

Comment: @acw1668 If OP removes `table.place(...)` and moves the `table.pack(...)` to the end, there will be no need for `.grid`

Comment: @TheLizzard I said using `grid()` is easier, not must.

Comment: Your code doesn't have any data in the table. Also, you've made the window un-resizeable and the scrollbar cannot be used.

Comment: Ohh Thankyou @acw1668 and TheLizzard for helping me out. This was such a silly mistake btw :)